# Angular app hangs when POST request is given, Chrome console gives error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

So I am a newbie in MEAN world. I am referring to this book Write Modern Web Apps With The Mean Stack Mongodb Express Angularjs and Node.js. So in this book, they teach us how to build a Twitter close using the MEAN stack. I have just copied the code  from the book but it is not working. Can you help me out?

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "socialapp",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.0",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.30"
  }
}
```

server.js

```js
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var Post = require('./models/post')

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/api/posts', function (req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    res.json(posts)
  })
})

app.post('/api/posts', function (req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post({
    username: req.body.username,
    body: req.body.body
  })
  post.save(function (err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    res.json(201, post)
  })
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on', 3000)
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('layouts/posts.html', { root: __dirname });
})
```

db.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/social', function () {
  console.log('mongodb connected')
})
module.exports = mongoose
```

models/post.js

```js
var db = require('../db')
var Post = db.model('Post', {
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  body:     { type: String, required: true },
  date:     { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
})
module.exports = Post
```

layouts/posts.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='PostsCtrl' class='container'>
    <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
    <form role='form'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <input ng-model='postBody' class='form-control' />
          <span class='input-group-btn'>
            <button ng-click='addPost()' class='btn btn-default'>Add Post</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul class='list-group'>
      <li ng-repeat='post in posts' class='list-group-item'>
        <strong>@{{ post.username }}</strong>
        <span>{{ post.body }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    // create our app module
    var app = angular.module('app', [])

    // create the PostsCtrl module
    // dependency inject $scope
    app.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {

      $scope.addPost = function () {
          if ($scope.postBody) {
            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/posts', {
            username: 'rahul23khanna',
            body: $scope.postBody
            }).success(function (post) {
              $scope.posts.unshift(post)
                $scope.postBody = null
                })
            } 
          }

      // starting data
     $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts')
     .success(function (posts) {
          $scope.posts = posts
      })
   })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.` - There might be an error on the server side (node.js). Do you see any error messages there? What do you see in the server log? Is your local mongoDB up and running?

Comment: @Michael no error messages. mongodb up and running.. I updated to the latest version of Chrome and it worked.. Thanks 